# Координаты пикселя во фрагментном шейдере

Tags: java, android, opengl, libgdx

Подскажите, хочу с помощью шейдера, перекрасить материал модели,но,не могу понять как получить координаты текущего пикселя, подскажите как узнать местоположение его, чтобы можно было определенные пиксели перекрасить?
Использую libgdx

Comment: координаты на экране или координаты относительно модели?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ если можно, подскажите,  как на экране и относительно модели, буду очень признателен.
У меня есть прямоугольник, без текстуры, и я хочу его, к примеру, на половину перекрасить другим цветом, и хочу знать, в каких координатах нахожусь, чтобы знать в какой цвет красить, типа прогресс бар )

Comment: координаты пикселя на экране - gl_FragCoord.xy , мировые координаты пикселя - находятся интерполяцией координат вершин, образующих треугольник, в котором находится пиксель

Comment: и да, я это забыл написать - интерполяцию делает gpu, просто устанавливаете атрибут вершине и записываете в вершинном шейдере его в varying, а во фрагментном получаете уже интерполированное значение

Comment: @StrangerintheQ спасибо большое за подробный ответ, и можете ещё подсказать, установить атрибут вершине вот так ?
`VertexAttribute vertexAttributes = new VertexAttribute(VertexAttributes.Usage.Position, 3, ShaderProgram.POSITION_ATTRIBUTE);`

Comment: я точно не скажу, в разных фреймворках по-разному, поищите пример с разноцветным треугольником для libgdx, обычно он есть, в нем цвета это атрибуты вершин, примерно такой https://camo.githubusercontent.com/630c78b71e71cb51fd979c5282bcbdc864cb22ba/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f6d5043643230572e706e67

Comment: @StrangerintheQ спасибо большое )